# how to check if string exist in list of strings in Gatling Scala

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

## How to check if `ponkipong` is present in `activeids` using [**Gatling**] *[check](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/)* - [***Scala***] ?

```json
{
  "activeids": [
    "ironblossom",
    "draw_on",
    "ponkipong",
    "summer22",
    "morphimagus"
  ]
}
```

> Have tried  `` .check(jmesPath("activeids[?contains(@, 'ponkipong') == `true`]").transform(_.length >= 1).is(true)) ``   but
> doesn't work.

> Also not sure how to do this using jsonPath.

---

---

### Though, Kind of a workaround I am currently using is this.

```scala
.check(bodyString.saveAs("response_data"))
.check(
  checkIf((response: Response, session: Session) => {
    val dde = "ponkipong"
    val is_dde_active_not_present = if ((Json.parse(session("response_data").as[String].stripMargin) \ "activeids").as[Seq[String]].indexOf(dde) >= 0) false else true
    is_dde_active_not_present
  }) {
    // this check is to make forceful fail if checkIf fails
    jsonPath("$.activeids[*]").count.is(-1)
  }
)
```

But, doesn’t look like a solution.

Need help to do it in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, I tend to use [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) whenever possible, [as explained here](https://gatling.io/2019/07/introducing-jmespath-support/).

In Scala:

```scala
jmesPath("contains(activeids, 'ponkipong')").ofType[Boolean].is(true)
```

In Java (recommended since Gatling 3.7):

```java
jmesPath("contains(activeids, 'ponkipong')").ofBoolean().is(true)
```